# Why does adding a CSS file to Shiny navbarPage create a blank tab?

Tags: css, shiny, navbar

I am ultimately trying to add a background image and logo to my shiny app that utilizes the navbarPage layout. Adding a simple CSS file with the background image I want creates this blank li object in the navbar.

Even when the CSS file is **completely blank**, I get the same problem. Somehow, the mere inclusion of a CSS file creates the issue. Any clues?

I had working version before I needed to include the logo in the top left corner....

[image]

[image]

**Working version with background image but no logo:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, there is an argument for the header in `navbarPage` called header. This will work when tags$header will put the css file in the navbar

```
             ui <- navbarPage('title,
                      header = inlcludeCSS('www/css/file/css'),
                      theme = shinytheme('flatly'),
                    .........
             ) # end UI
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to include your css file in a different way?

I would suggest to use **tag$head**:

```
tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "www/theme2.css")
)
```

also, you can add your logo using:

```
title=div(img(src="logo.jpg"))
```

and then add some styling to the div. I think it's much easier solution than playing with img tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
ui <- tagList(
  includeCSS("www/theme2.css"),
  navbarPage(
    ......
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i also had a same issue.
I found a [post in github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/827) that there are some `shiny` users had a problem with this blank or ghost tab when they are using CSS. In my case, I got the blank tab when using `navbarPage()` and used `useShinydashboard()`, not when adding the CSS. I think this issue is not specifically caused by adding CSS.
I suggest you to use `tagList` as mentioned by Stéphane Laurent. Assuming you also add some `shinydashboard` function in your application like I did, here is my solution looks like.

```
ui <- tagList(
  useShinydashboard(),
  navbarPage(title = "Title",
             theme = shinytheme("united"),
             Home_ui,
             Map_ui
  )
)
```

It would be great to share your findings if you have solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually ended up switching to shinydashboard() and then using the `tags$head` for my `custom.css` as suggested by @Justyna. Next time i use navbarPage, i will try this!